# Связи в SQL по полю и названию таблицы

Tags: php, sql

Можно ли дефолтным sql делать связь между полем и названием таблицы ?

Т.е. например

```
— table 1
| table_name |
| users |

— users
| id | name |
| 1 | .......... |
```

Если я удаляю запись в table1, то удаляется таблица, имя которой прописано в table_name

Или только через логику php ?

Comment: Можно использовать триггер или просто написать SQL запрос, который вместе с удалением строки таблицы удаляет таблицу с аналогичным названием. Если напишите какой SQL используете будет проще дать Вам решение

Comment: @Kunoichi 10.3.22-MariaDB - вы об этом ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать SQL запрос, который удалит таблицу соответствующую удаляемой строчке или создать триггер, который будет удалять таблицу при любом запросе на удаление строки:

SQL запрос может выглядеть так:

```
DECLARE @tableName varchar(MAX) = 'users'
DELETE FROM [Table1] WHERE [table_name] = @tableName;
DECLARE @cmd varchar(MAX)
SET @cmd = 'DROP TABLE [' + @tableName + ']';
EXEC(@cmd)
```

Триггер может выглядеть так:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Table1_delete
AFTER DELETE
   ON Table1 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

    DECLARE @cmd varchar(MAX)
    SET @cmd = 'DROP TABLE [' + OLD.[table_name] + ']';
    EXEC(@cmd)

END;
```

Могу ошибаться в синтаксисе запросов для MariaDB, но полагаю смысл ясен